# How to create a set of equations using coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions

We were tasked to graph an object for our project.
We plot the eggplant on a cartesian plane and have coordinates for it
The catch is we need to make different combinations of equations to connect those coordinates (much like connect the dots)

Is there someway this can be easier? Is there a way where we use the coordinates to find the proper equations for it to connect?

Comment: You need to elaborate what you are looking for a little more. Are you trying to find a curve in the plane that passes through specified points?

Comment: Yes copper, exactly like that. Preferably multiple points.